# Реверс таймера DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как заставить таймер DispatcherTimer идти в обратную сторону?

```
    public TestTimer()
    {
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        StartTimer();            
    }

    private DispatcherTimer Timer;

    private int _seconds;
    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return _seconds; }
        set
        {
            if(value > -1 && value < 61)
                _seconds = value;
        }
    }

    private int _minutes;
    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return _minutes; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 61)
                _minutes = value;
        }
    }

    private int _hours;
    public int Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 25)
                _hours = value;
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        Timer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        Timer.Stop();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Seconds > 59)
        {
            Seconds = 0;
            Minutes++;

            if (Minutes > 59)
            {
                Minutes = 0;
                Hours++;

                if (Hours > 23)
                    Hours = 0;
            }
        }
        Seconds++;

        TimeFormat = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
            Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    }
```

Comment: Это как? В прошлое? Какое отношение к вопросу имеет приведенный код?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Если задать начальное время больше 0, например, 21/10/15 (чч/мм/сс), то таймер должен идти в обратную сторону. Приведенный код заставляет время идти только вперед, а нужно еще и назад

Comment: Что значит *Приведенный код заставляет время идти только вперед*? Вы даже код метода `TimerTick` не привели

Comment: @АндрейNOP Сорри, добавил TimerTick

Comment: Ну так вам надо изменить код метода `TimerTick`. А вообще я вам рекомендую пользоваться стандартной структурой `DateTime` (или `TimeSpan`), там будет всё очень просто: `currentTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(1)` или `currentTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(-1)` в зависимости от нужного условия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы не все показали, что вам надо, но для того кода, что я вижу, таймер не нужен.

```
public class TestTimer
{
    public TestTimer()
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    public int Seconds
    {
        get => (DateTime.UtcNow - _startTime).Seconds;
    }

    public int Minutes
    {
        get => (DateTime.UtcNow - _startTime).Minutes;
    }

    public int Hours
    {
        get => (DateTime.UtcNow - _startTime).Hours;
    }

    private DateTime _startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public string TimeFormat => string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
}
```

Как использовать

```
var timer = new TestTimer();
timer.StartTimer();

Thread.Sleep(2000);
Console.WriteLine(timer.TimeFormat);
```

Вывод

```
00:00:02
```

Comment: А можно как-то сделать, чтобы таймер обновлялся раз в 2 секунды и показывал только нечетные секунды?

Comment: @DimaKozyr этот таймер вообще никак не обновляется, он просто показывает сколько вемени прошло с момента старта. Если вам надо как то по другому показывать четные секунды, то вам надо добавить логику в свойство `public int Seconds { get { .... }} `